# OOP - init method not changing class attribute

Tags: python, class, init, class-attributes

I am trying to use the `transfer_to_saving` method in the `CheckingAccount` class. However, whenever I create a `SavingAccount` object, the `self.has_saving = True` does not change the class attribute to `True`. So, whenever I try to transfer funds, it prints `Must create a saving account`.

```
class CheckingAccount(Account):
    balance = 0

    def __init__(self, account_number, pin):
        super().__init__(account_number)
        self.SavingAccount = SavingAccount
        self.pin = pin

    def deposit(self, amount):
        old_bal = self.balance
        self.balance += amount
        print(f'Previous Balance: ${old_bal}\nDeposit amount: ${amount}\nNew Balance: ${self.balance}')

    def withdraw(self, pin, amount):
        if pin == self.pin:
            self.balance -= print('Insufficient funds') if amount > self.balance else amount
        else:
            print('Invalid PIN')

    def transfer_to_saving(self, amount):
        if self.SavingAccount.has_saving is False:
            print('Must create a saving account')
        elif amount > self.balance:
            print('Insufficient funds')
        else:
            self.SavingAccount.balance += amount
            self.balance -= amount


class SavingAccount(Account):
    balance = 0
    has_saving = False

    def __init__(self, account_number):
        super().__init__(account_number)
        self.CheckingAccount = CheckingAccount
        self.has_saving = True

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
```

Am I doing this right? Shouldn't the `init` method be changing the class attribute?

---UPDATE---

The goal I am trying to accomplish is to find out whether the user has already created a saving account. I have additional User classes that I did not include since it would be a bit overkill. However, the goal is to prevent a user from transferring money from checking to saving if they don't have a saving account.

Comment: what you are trying to do is probably not what you want to do.    its tough to say without knowing why you want to have a has_saving flag variable associated with a class or instance of that class that already is representing a savings account.   as noted by one of the answers you are likley misusing the reference to the class names and assigning instance variables of that name to the self. vars of the same name.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing, misusing the reference to the class names. I appreciate the feedback. I am making some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually creating an instance of `SavingAccount` with this line:

```
        self.SavingAccount = SavingAccount
```

You are assigning the `self.SavingAccount` **attribute** to the `SavingAccount` **class** defined below.

You need to call the `SavingAccount` constructor, like this:

```
        self.saving_account = SavingAccount(account_number)
```

Note that the Python convention is to use `lower_snake_case` for attributes/variables, and `UpperCamelCase` for class names.

You are doing the same thing on this line in the `SavingAccount` constructor:

```
        self.CheckingAccount = CheckingAccount
```

I'm not sure what the goal is here, but if you want every `SavingAccount` to hold a reference to a `CheckingAccount` and vice versa, it might be cleaner to do it like this:

```
class CheckingAccount(Account):

    def __init__(self, account_number, pin):
        super().__init__(account_number)
        self.saving_account = SavingAccount(account_number, self)
        self.pin = pin

class SavingAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, account_number, checking_account):
        super().__init__(account_number)
        self.checking_account = checking_account
```

With this, whenever you create a `CheckingAccount` you will get a corresponding `SavingAccount` and they will each hold a reference to each other. I think it's still a bit weird conceptually, since the account numbers would be the same, so it might be better to just create them separately like this:

```
class CheckingAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, account_number, pin):
        super().__init__(account_number)
        self.saving_account = None  # to be assigned later
        self.pin = pin

class SavingAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, account_number):
        super().__init__(account_number)
        self.checking_account = None  # to be assigned later


checking_account_number = 123
checking = CheckingAccount(checking_account_number)
saving_account_number = 456
saving = SavingAccount(saving_account_number)
checking.saving_account = saving
saving.checking_account = checking
```

Finally, the `has_saving` attribute of `SavingAccount` is not necessary at all. A cleaner way to check if a `SavingAccount` is to use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
    def transfer_to_saving(self, amount):
        if not isinstance(self.saving_account, SavingAccount):
            print('Must create a saving account')
        elif amount > self.balance:
            print('Insufficient funds')
        else:
            self.saving_account.balance += amount
            self.balance -= amount
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation (and all the extra goodies you provided)!

Comment: ```self.saving_account = None  # to be assigned later```

This is exactly what I was hoping to do. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the `self.has_saving = True`  you are establishing an instance variable that is part of the instance.   you are not modifying the class variable. to modify the class variable you would need to use the class name instead of `self.` reference.